# Can't search for substring from object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a "Search File" page that lets users enter a string to find some local files (with NodeJS). I want it so the user can type a part of the string and still get results. For example, if they only typed "ha" then all files that contain the string "ha" should be displayed.

Here's my current code:

```
app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
  //to read all the file names in the directory, returns ["file_01.txt", "file_02.txt"]
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  
  const userInput = req.body.userInput;
  const subArr = fileNames.filter((str) => str.includes(userInput));
  console.log(subArr); //returns empty
  res.render("search.ejs");
});
```

However, if I declare it explicitly:

```
const abc = ["ab", "bc", "cd"];
const subArr = abc.filter((str) => str.includes(userInput));
console.log(subArr) //returns an array of words that contain the user input, just like I want it to
```

Why can't I filter from fileNames but it works with abc? Please help, thank you!

EDIT:

Solved! Thank you to everyone who answered my question, especially to jakub podhaisky

The answer is to convert both the userInput and the str to lower case. This is the only change I made and everything works great:

```
const subArr = fileNames.filter((str) => 
     str.toLowerCase().includes(userInput.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: Can you debug the filter statement? What's the `userInput` did you get?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to setup your body parser? I think issue may be in that the userInput is actually empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the filtering is working fine considering that it works with abc...
In my past experience the issue with includes method is that it is case sensitive and i was trying to debug for so long
try to convert both strings to lowercase or uppercase:

```
const subArr = fileNames.filter((str) => 
str.toLowerCase().includes(userInput.toLowerCase()));
```

also make sure that everything works as expected some might not like it but console.log is my best friend:

```
app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
    const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
    console.log("Directory:", __dirname); // Debug
    console.log("Files in directory:", fileNames); // Debug

    const userInput = req.body.userInput;
    console.log("User Input:", userInput); // Debug

    // Case-insensitive filtering
    const subArr = fileNames.filter((str) => 
    str.toLowerCase().includes(userInput.toLowerCase()));

    console.log("Filtered Files:", subArr); // Debug

    res.render("search.ejs", { files: subArr }); // Ensure you're passing 
    the filtered list to your template
});
```

Check where the is not doing what it is supposed to do so you can pinpoint the issue
Make sure __dirname is the directory that you looking for
Make sure that fileNames contains files of the said directory and so on...

Comment: It works! Yay! .toLowerCase() is the answer to my problem. That was the only issue, since the readdir, userInput, and value passing work great if I'm not filtering the fileNames. Thank you so much!